# Yocto compiling old kernel in newer distro

Tags: gcc, yocto, bitbake, yocto-recipe

I have an embedded device with a custom kernel (3.14). Until now I have used jethro distribution to generate kernel and fs image. I would like to upgrade a bit and move my machine to dunfell distro but I have several problems.

Trying myself and based on googling around I came to that conclusion compiling an old kernel with (much) newer gcc is kinda impossible.
So what I have tried is copying gcc_4.9 recipes into dunfell and set the gcc (and glibc?) version for that particular machine. I found it very difficult to solve this as well because

**The glibc and gcc recipe structures changed a lot and use very differenc environment variables, eg. there are no more glibc-initial packages and virtual/${TARGET_SYS}libc-for-gcc packages are not provided by any glibc anymore.**
**There are a lot of changes in the gcc recipes as well (environment variables, dependencies, etc) and I assume they have also modified the sources for that purpose (providing empy headers or such  - so no "-initial" packages needed). As much as I could backtrack it the "transition" happened betwen thud and warrior distros.**

What I'm asking for / things you can help me with:

- if someone is familiar with this "transition" in gcc recipes/sources and can explain it or point me to a source where I can find relevant information or
- if someone already has a working gcc/libc package for dunfell thats <= 7.0 version or
- if someone has any idea I can try to make it work

I would greatly appreciate it. Thank you.

Comment: In the OE layer directory there is at least [one recipe](https://layers.openembedded.org/layerindex/recipe/125744/) (along with some funky patches) for kernel 3.10 on dunfell (based on the description, at least. I have no other proof if it even compiles). It could serve as an inspiration, if it works. But generally the main idea doesn't sound too good. (I know... in the embedded world sometimes it's nigh impossible to bump kernel due to garbage/unmaintained drivers...)

Comment: @skandigraun I really appretiate your help. I have put this project aside for now. Maybe a bit later I will give it a try.